# From winSCP to FileZilla and back - musing on some conversions

Tags: linux, ssh, sftp

From winSCP to FileZilla and back - musing on some conversions

i have used Winscp for several years. - On the machine in office - where Win is installed.

At home i have Linux of course. FileZilla does not support any kind of import from other applications.
well there would be a help if i would write a script to convert WinSCP INI configuration file data.
With that data port to FileZilla i would be able to port over the data to FileZilla XML configuration file.

Hmm - i guess that should not be that difficult. Guess that this would  be worth the effort.

**The goal:** i could try to do a convertion of all the passwords encrypted by WinSCP to an unencrypted (or base64-encoded) form that FileZilla 
uses would be the most challenging (if we think of the save passwords).

The nice thing would be  - if i get aware that WinSCP is better in several tasks i could also switch back,

Well this switch back could be done easily by importing the  new FileZilla sessions to WinSCP: - see this page https://winscp.net/eng/docs/ui_import

so far the ideas to work with WinSCP and Filezilla

What do you think bout this ideas to use both systems and to convert the data: from winSCP to FileZilla and back - musing on some conversions

Comment: You should learn about SSH public/private key pairs and go from there.

Comment: In Linux your SSH credentials are shared between applications. And some file managers will transparently connect to systems where you have SSH credentials.